# Powershell and Nested JSON

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, hashtable

I have the following JSON

```
{
  "method": "exec",
  "params": [
    {
      "url": "/sys/login/user",
      "data": [
        {
          "user": "MyUsername",
          "passwd": "MyPassword"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "id": 1,
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

I'm trying to build this JSON using Powershell, but the output is not correct, below is my code.

```
$fullJson=@{}
$params=@()
$paramsdata=@()
$paramsdata+=@{"user"="mailapi"}
$paramsdata+=@{"passwd"="**********"}
$params+=@{"url"="/sys/login/user"}
$params+=@{"data"=$paramsdata}
$fullJson.Add("method", "exec")
$fullJson.Add("params",$params)
$fullJson.Add("id", "1")
$fullJson.Add("ver", "2.0")
$JsonBody=$fullJson | ConvertTo-Json
$x=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://10.10.10.10/jsonrpc -Body $JsonBody -Method Post
```

The output is the below

```
{
    "method":  "exec",
    "params":  [
                   {
                       "url":  "/sys/login/user"
                   },
                   {
                       "data":  "System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable"
                   }
               ],
    "id":  "1",
    "ver":  "2.0"
}
```

The problem is DATA properties is not correct format, it should be an a nested array inside the first one, but it seems that its being added as a hashtable.

This problem is the data array should be built like this one below

```
"params": [
    {
      "url": "/sys/login/user",
      "data": [
        {
          "user": "MyUsername",
          "passwd": "MyPassword"
        }
      ]
```

But with my code, its being built like this

```
"params":  [
                   {
                       "url":  "/sys/login/user"
                   },
                   {
                       "data":  "System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable"
                   }
               ],
```

Any help in updating this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-Depth` [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6) in `ConvertTo-Json` :

> Specifies how many levels of contained objects are included in the
>   JSON representation. The default value is 2.

Your desired depth is 4 (object -> params -> data -> username/password) :

```bsh
$JsonBody=$fullJson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
```

Comment: The Code should be sent like this
```
"params": [
    {
      "url": "/sys/login/user",
      "data": [
        {
          "user": "MyUsername",
          "passwd": "MyPassword"
        }
      ]
```

But using my code, it's being built like this
```
"params":  [
                   {
                       "url":  "/sys/login/user"
                   },
                   {
                       "data":  "System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable"
                   }
               ],
```

Comment: @FarisMlaeb I misunderstood your question and now I have edited my answer.